# how to properly remove Delphi-RAD Studio 10.4

Tags: delphi

I downloaded Delphi 10.4.2 Sydney Community Edition. During installation, it threw an error:

> Unable to connect to "getIt104" server (404 error)

I uninstalled and tried reinstalling, but received the same error.

I tried installing it in `D:\Delphi` instead of the default path (`C:\Program Files\...`), and now I'm getting a different error:

> RAD studio already installed. Do you want to remove everything from registry?

Clicking yes, gives an error:

> Please remove previous version first

I removed all "Embarcadero/Borland" entries from Path/Registry Editor, and all visible folders in `C:\` and `D:\`.  I still get the "previous version found" error.

How to proceed with this? Is there any tool/utility which can remove the product entirely?

[image: Rad Studio error]

Comment: Asking for tools is offtopic here

Comment: Getit for 10.4 was offline in the last day or two.  There was a bug report filed for it: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-38604

Comment: I am not asking for tools.

Comment: See [Error on loading data from the server getit-104.embarcadero.com](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/4198-error-on-loading-data-from-the-server-getit-104embarcaderocom/): "*That server [getit-104] was shutdown [in Nov 2020]. Change GetIt's configuration to use https://getit.embarcadero.com instead of https://getit-104.embarcadero.com*"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step by step guide:

https://blogs.embarcadero.com/manual-uninstall-of-rad-studio-delphi-cbuilder-10-4-sydney/

> Under your Control Panel’s Program and Features Add/Remove Program uninstall the following entries:
>
> RAD Studio 10.4 version 21.0
>
> Please follow these instructions to remove any leftover files:
>
> - If Windows 64-bit, remove the C:Program Files (x86)EmbarcaderoStudio21.0 directory (or the custom folder you had used).
> - Remove the C:UsersPublicDocumentsEmbarcaderoStudio21.0 directory
> - Remove the C:ProgramDataEmbarcaderoStudio21.0 directory.
> - Remove the %APPDATA%EmbarcaderoBDS21.0 directory.
> - Remove the HKEY_CURRENT_USERSOFTWAREEmbarcaderoBDS21.0 registry key
> - If Windows 64-bit, remove the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESOFTWAREWow6432NodeEmbarcaderoBDS21.0
> - If Windows 64-bit, remove the following files from C:WindowsSysWOW64:
>
>   - BDEAdmin.*
>   - CC32*.DLL
>   - Midas.*
>   - Xerces*.DLL
>
> Field testers should also do the following (and others may want to as well):
>
> - Delete the Godzilla license from License manager before uninstalling it or during the installation of RAD Studio 10.4 Sydney

Comment: You should copy the relevant content from the blog site and add it here in case the site is offline.

Comment: I did that but same problem.

Comment: Finally able to uninstall but installation hangs in between. No error/warning message. Tried thrice. Will try again before giving up.